# Creating a gesture definition for a simple static gesture using Kinect - part 2

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, gesture-recognition

I have implemented the sample code and used the 'Joint.ID' instead of 'Joint.Type', I just need to work out whether/how this code can be continuously checked within a loop. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Notes of advice:-

1. `void newSensor_AllFramesReady` fires when Color/Depth/Skeleton are synchronized. **I'm not too sure where to place this method.**
2. `checkHand` method needs to be checked every round of the thread.

Code so far:-

```
void newSensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    //Get a skeleton

    SkeletonFrame skeletonSet = e.SkeletonFrame;

    SkeletonData skeleton = (from s in skeletonSet.Skeletons
                             where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                             select s).FirstOrDefault();

    if (skeleton == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (skeleton != null)
    {
        checkHand(skeleton.Joints[JointID.Head], skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandRight], skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandLeft]);
    }
}

public void checkHand(Joint head, Joint rhand, Joint lhand)
{
    if (rhand.Position.X > head.Position.Y)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Right hand up!");
    }
    else if (lhand.Position.Y > head.Position.Y)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Left hand up!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you assign newSensor_AllFramesReady as the event handler for AllFramesReady event. There's no need to put any of it in the loop. newSensor_AllFramesReady will be called 30 times a second (or whatever is kinect's refresh rate).

```
Kinect.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(newSensor_AllFramesReady);
```